# What is the Difference between Web.config and global.asax?

Tags: asp.net

What is the Difference between Web.config and global.asax ?

Comment: A lot! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: how about you learn the basics of asp.net before you ask a question.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global.asax for more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web.config file specifies configuration data for the .NET application. The global.asax file handles application- and session-level events

Answer (score 6):

Global.asax contains code which is executed.
Web.config contains configuration settings of web application, for example connection string, included libraries, namespaces, users and groups access permissions to virtual directories, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Web.config is... well a config file. Global.asax is a place where you put global event handlers like Application_Start, Application_End, etc. (global to your application).